# No navigation links on 404 pages

Tags: 7, navigation

When I visit a page that does not exist, I expect to still see the primary and secondary links as on any other page, but what I get is no navigation links in the 404 page. See also [No navigation links on 404 pages](http://drupal.org/node/233807).

I have found a solution, but I am happy if something else can fix this (possibly without using extra modules).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it by defining a page in a custom module.

Create a page for the category "Page not found" using `hook_menu()`.

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items['page-not-found'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'MODULE_page_not_found',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MODULE_page_not_found() {
  drupal_set_title('Page not found');
  $cust_err = "";
  $cust_err = $cust_err . "The requested page " . current_path() . " could not be found";
  return $cust_err;
}
```

The page callback uses `current_path()` to return the path of the page causing the 404 error.

Go to *Admin > Config > System > Site-information*, and enter **page-not-found** (same name as defined in `hook_menu`) under *Default 404 (not found) page*.

[image: snap1]

Now the error page appears like in the following screenshot.

[image: snap2]

It is clear that it contains all the navigation links, and also the page URL producing the error (very similar to the original page not found). And the module mentioned in the answer above by @[Nikhil](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4471/nikhil-m) will output "The requested page could not be found." but does not contain the URL of the page causing the error.

Comment: Are you sure i will get the navigation links in the page ?

Comment: @NikhilM I've tested this and and the screenshots are real ;-)

Comment: I've test it right now. I customize the text shown in page not found page. but apparently it shows the default text from somewhere else! what is going on in drupal?

Comment: I was struggling with this yesterday at work, very nice solution.

Answer (score 11):

There is a module to make this work [404 Navigation](http://drupal.org/project/navigation404)

> On 404 Not Found error pages, Drupal will skip rendering of all the
>   navigation links of your website for performance reasons*. Some of
>   these include:
>
> The "Primary links" block and any other menu links block. The Primary
>   links and Secondary links of your theme.
>   * Unless you have configured a "Default 404 (not found) page" on admin/config/system/site-information.

Also there is a [Patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/233807-404-normal-page-cached_0.patch) to fix this in D7.

In D8 See [THIS](http://qa.drupal.org/pifr/test/175159) Also [THIS](http://drupal.org/node/233807#comment-5027558)

Answer (score 6):

There are also good module alternatives:

- [Search 404](http://drupal.org/project/search404)

  > Instead of showing a standard "404 Page not found", this module performs a search on the keywords in the URL, e.g. if a user goes to http://example.com/does/not/exist, this module will do a search for "does not exist" and shows the result of the search instead of the 404 page. This should help retain visitors coming in from old URLs linked from other sites or from search indices.
- [Fast 404](http://drupal.org/project/fast_404)

  > Drupal has expensive 404 errors. On an 'average' site with an 'average' module load, you can be looking at 60-100MB of memory being consumed on your server to deliver a 404. Consider a page with a bad .gif link and a missing .css file. That page will generate 2 404s along with the actual load of the page. You are most likely looking at 180MB of memory to server that page rather than the 60MB it should take.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by defining a page in a custom module.

Create a page for the category "Page not found" using hook_menu().

```
 function MODULE_menu() {
   $items['page-not-found'] = array(
     'title' => '',
     'page callback' => 'MODULE_page_not_found',
     'access callback' => TRUE,
   );
   return $items;
 }

 function MODULE_page_not_found() {
   drupal_set_title('Page not found');
   $cust_err = "";
   $cust_err = $cust_err . "The requested page " . current_path() . " ould not be found";
   return $cust_err;
 }
```

It's almost good. But this code returns:

> "The requested page page-not-found could not be found"

need change ***current_path()*** to ***request_uri()*** and will return:

> "The requested page /request_uri could not be found"

Comment: I changed the error message to `t('The requested page "@path" could not be found.', array('@path' => request_uri()));`. This way the default Drupal translation is used when your site is multilangual.

Comment: You are right, it's good practice =)